# Sorting list based on Search Query

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

I have a list of strings and I have to sort it based on some search string.

```
My Search String is Home Depot

MyList = ['Depot Home','Rollins Home Furniture','HomeDepot 1346','Home Depot']
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Sorted list: ['HomeDepot 1346','Home Depot','Depot Home','Rollins Home Furniture']
```

In the sorted list first element is exact match of search string removing spaces, Second is also exact Match with space and 3rd element is partial Match of Depot(in alphabetical order) and 4th element is also a partial match for Home (alphabetical order so placed after Depot)

**What I did so far:**

```
searchquery_startswith=[w for w in Mylist if w.startswith('HOME DEPOT'.strip())]
searchquery_substring= [w for w in Mylist if ('HOME DEPOT' in w and w not in searchquery_startswith)]
```

I know I can do something like this but I'm looking for more pythonic way to achieve this. All help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can define a custom function that ranks your words given your search query and then use this in combination with `sorted`.

```
def search_for_home_depot(word):
    result = 0
    if word.lower().startswith('HOME DEPOT'.lower().replace(' ','')):
        result += -2

    if 'HOME DEPOT'.lower() in word.lower():
        result += -1

    return result

l = ['Depot Home','Rollins Home Furniture','HomeDepot 1346','Home Depot']

print([search_for_home_depot(x) for x in l])

print(sorted(l, key=search_for_home_depot))

> [0, 0, -2, -1]
> ['HomeDepot 1346', 'Home Depot', 'Depot Home', 'Rollins Home Furniture']
```

You can adapt the conditions and weightings of each individual check to finegrain your results.

Comment: it fails for this list = ['Depot Home','Rollins Home Furniture','HomeDepot 1346','Home Depot','Cryce Depot','China Home']

Comment: I'm expecting : ['HomeDepot 1346', 'Home Depot', 'Depot Home', 'Cryce Depot', 'China Home','Rollins Home Furniture' ]

Comment: You seem to have clear rules which words come before which other words. Just encode these rules into the function `search_for_home_depot` assigning lower scores to the words you want to list first. My answer should just get you started to reach your own solution.

Comment: I'm not looking for an approach but a faster and easiest way to approach this. Is it something do-able also in Python or I might have to go for some Python full text search libraries. However you deserve an Upvote.